# No search results while using API Key to retrieve information using Python

Tags: python, api, search, ssl-certificate

Mouser is a website where electronic components can be bought and are listed with their details and technical parameters.

To automate the search of parts from this website, I am trying to automate the processing using the [Mouser API Key for part search](https://api.mouser.com/api/docs/ui/index).

I am trying to retrieve Part Number details from [mouser.com](https://www.mouser.com/) using API key. But, I get no search results.
Below is the python script for the same.

```
import requests
import json

api_key = "my API Key"
part_number = "LM258AMDREP" #Part Number

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

data = {
    "SearchByPartnumberRequest": {
        "MouserPartNumber": part_number
    }
}

url = f"https://api.mouser.com/api/v1/search/partnumber?apikey={api_key}"

try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print ("Error: " + str(err))
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # catastrophic error. bail.
    print ("Error: " + str(e))
```

The output I get is:

```
{'Errors': [{'Id': 0, 'Code': 'Required', 'Message': 'Required', 'ResourceKey': 'Required', 'ResourceFormatString': None, 
'ResourceFormatString2': None, 'PropertyName': 'Request'}], 'SearchResults': None}
```

If I remove the `verify=False`, I get following error

```
Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.mouser.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/search/partnumber?apikey=e9226156-491c-4635-bfcd-5285f80244cf (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)')))
```

Is there some other version/procedure to get the part details.

Answer (score 0):

Cause by default verify is set to True

See [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=verifying#ssl-cert-verification)

Answer (score 0):

in your data, you should write "SearchByPartRequest" instead of "SearchByPartnumberRequest"